# Netsuite Saved Search check for field on related record

Tags: netsuite

I have a Saved Search (type is invoice) and I need to check for (custom) field on Cash Refund. How can I do this? (I've tried "Deposit/Refund transaction fields", but that doesn't do anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: In the Saved Search under Criteria pick "Applying Transaction fields", pick the custom field from the "Cash Refund".

That worked for me.. but make sure you do some tests..